# Retrieving values from map <<object>, int> exhibits strange behavior

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I am reproducing a problem I have with maps in a project, or which I implemented the following debugging code. I am having trouble retrieving the integer values  in  a map from  Point2 objects as keys.
I have implemented the overloading of the Point2 objects as shown in the code. Point2 objects are ordered according to the value of _label.

The map _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel gets its elements inserted successfully, but lines 116,120,124 and 128 behave strangely.They should just assign the value of the corresponding POint2 object to the corresponding variables.

-line 116 does an insertion into the map, as shown in the figure and label1 is set to 0 instead of getting its value 27;

-the other 3 lines just set the variables label2, label3 and label4 to 0 instead of to the values 17,47 and 37;

**What is going on? If I am doing something wrong, how do I fix it to get the desired behavior?**

```
  class Point2
    {
        private:
            double _coordinates[2];
            int _label = -2;
       public:
            Point2(const double x = 0.0, const double y = 0.0){_coordinates[0]=x;_coordinates[1]=y;}
    
            int getFirstCoordinate() const{ return _coordinates[0];}
            int getSecondCoordinate() const{ return _coordinates[1];}
            int getPointLabel() const{ return _label;}
            void setPointLabel(const int label){_label =label;}
            friend bool operator< (const Point2& p1, const Point2& p2 ){
    
                return p1._label < p2._label;
            }
            Point2& operator =(const Point2 &point)
            {
                _coordinates[0] = point.getFirstCoordinate();
                _coordinates[1] = point.getSecondCoordinate();
                _label = point.getPointLabel();
                return *this;
           }
            Point2(const Point2 &p1){
              _coordinates[0]=p1._coordinates[0];
              _coordinates[1]=p1._coordinates[1];
              _label = p1._label;
    
            }
    
    };

    int main(){
         Point2 _intersectionVertices[4];
        
            _intersectionVertices[0]= Point2(10,20);
            _intersectionVertices[1]= Point2(11,21);
            _intersectionVertices[2]= Point2(12,21);
            _intersectionVertices[3]= Point2(13,31);
            Point2 p1 = Point2(10,20);
            Point2 p2 = Point2(11,21);
            Point2 p3 = Point2(12,31);
            Point2 p4 = Point2(13,41);
            p1.setPointLabel(1);
            p2.setPointLabel(2);
            p3.setPointLabel(3);
            p4.setPointLabel(4);
        
           int intersectionId ;
            map<Point2, int>_mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel;
            _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel.insert(pair<Point2, int>(p1,27));
            _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel.insert(pair<Point2, int>(p2,17));
            _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel.insert(pair<Point2, int>(p3,47));
            _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel.insert(pair<Point2, int>(p4,37));
        
            intersectionId = 0;
            int label1 = _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel[_intersectionVertices[intersectionId]]; //line 116 //I placed a debug point here
            cout <<"Label1 is"<<label1<<endl;
        
            intersectionId = 1;
            int label2 = _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel[_intersectionVertices[intersectionId]];//line 120
            cout <<"Label2 is"<<label2<<endl;
        
            intersectionId = 2;
            int label3 = _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel[_intersectionVertices[intersectionId]];//line 124
            cout <<"Label3 is"<<label3<<endl;
        
            intersectionId = 3;
            int label4 = _mapExtendedPointToIntersectionLabel[_intersectionVertices[intersectionId]];//line 128
            cout <<"Label4 is"<<label4<<endl;
        
            cout<<"the end"<<endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

Before line 116:

[image]

After line 116:

[image]

Comment: The code shown only ever has one entry in the map and thus does not reproduce the problem http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d43f98b4d3dff8f0. Please produce a [minimal reproduable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MooingDuck Sorry I forgot a piece of code where I set the values of _label I just added it

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible example. My original code uses more complicated data members

Comment: why the code has only one entry in the map is the precisely the problem

Comment: I have now 5 entries with your update, but it always retrieves the same value. Which is to be expected because `-2` is the smallest label and your comparison onyl takes that into account.

Comment: @Devolus, how would I fix it then? I really don't see it

Comment: In line 116 there is no insertion instruction, but it does an insertion

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Your user-defined assignment operator and copy constructor for `Point2` are totally unnecessary, as the compiler defaults are perfectly ok for the data types you have as member variables.  All you're doing when you introduce code that is not necessary is increase the chance for bugs to occur, as well as take away any optimizations that the compiler could perform.  The second thing is that you should actually check the return value of [map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).  It will tell you if the insertion was successful or not.

Comment: Also, the `map::operator[]` will insert an entry in the map automatically if the entry doesn't exist.  That's why you end up with 5 items.  You really should check your return values from the map operations, as well as do a more thorough job of debugging by using `map::find()` instead of just using `[ ]`.  A misuse of `[ ]` for map lookups is a big source of errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, thank you. Do you know any way how I can achieve the behavior of inserting in the map the values order by _label but look them up based on the key? In the answer below it says it is not possible with a a container, I am not discussing that, but maybe with two parallel containers it could be achieve some way?  I am completely clueless about this

Comment: Why do you need a map at all?  You say you want them in sorted order by _label but that doesn't require a map.  Just out of curiosity, why do they need to be sorted at all?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I am working on this https://bitbucket.org/FabioVicini/exercises/src/master/Projects/Project_1/. The code is here https://bitbucket.org/IMMANUEL17/pcs_project/src/master/. It is a requirement to number the intersection Points like in the  figures. While my algorithm already cuts the polygon I am having trouble assigning the numbers to the Points

Comment: So the label needs to be monotonically increasing even as more and more things are inserted.  A std::map is a balanced binary tree based on the key so if you use the label as the key then the only way to find something is to look at every node or use _label.  If you need to look at every node anyway then if you used a std::vector the index of the point would be the monotonically increasing label and you could use find_if to find the correct node.  If you really want to use a map then write your own lookup function that iterates through the nodes looking for the right item and returns the key.

Comment: Would this help: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.bimap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        friend bool operator< (const Point2& p1, const Point2& p2 )
        {    
            return p1._label < p2._label;
        }
```

The defined strict weak ordering of this custom class, that's used as a key, in the map, compares each class instance's `_label` value in order to determine thir strict weak ordering.

The shown code initializes `p1` through `p4`'s `_label`s to unique values, so they are correctly compared for uniqueness.

But for the map lookup is concerned, it uses the instances in the `_intersectionVertices` array, which all have their `_label`s at their default values of `-2`.

As far as the map is concerned, none of those values, from the `_intersectionVertices` array, are in the map. Because to determine that, only their `_label`s get compared, for the reasons explained above.

Comment: How can I achieve the desired behavior? I want the insertion to be made based on _label as shown, but the lookup to be made  using the instances in the _intersectionVertices.

Comment: I thought that for insertion, the < operator had to be used, but that for look up only the == operator should be used, therefore ignoring _label

Comment: `std::map` always uses the defined strict weak ordering for ***all*** map operations. Lookup, insert, etc... This cannot be changed. That's the only way that `std::map` (and all other associative containers) work. If you want for "the lookup to be made using the instances in the `_intersectionVertices` you have to set ***their*** `_label`s correctly.

Comment: any way I can achieve the behavior I described? Maybe with another container? The logic in my code depended on this

Comment: As I mentioned, ***all*** C++ containers work this way. Their third template parameter defaults to `std::less` and specifies their associative container's strict weak ordering. Full stop. End of story. The strict weak ordering defines the behavior of ***all*** container operations. And not that it matters: even if the containers worked the way you thought they worked, your custom class fails to implement the `==` overload, so that won't work anyway (but, that's irrelevant for the reasons stated).